# In Angular.js unit tests, is it convention to leave out the '$' in front of 'scope' but not '$rootScope' (or other injected services)?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, angularjs

I have noticed that in many peoples' example unit tests for Angular they leave out the "$" in front of scope like so:

```
// in beforeEach(inject(function() {})) call
scope = $rootScope.$new();
var ctrl = $controller({
    '$scope' : scope
});
```

Why has this convention been adopted by some people?  In the Angular docs they don't seem to make a fuss out of it, or mention it at all.

Answer (score 2):

Long story short, '$' is placed in front of services/variables that are injected into your code ($rootScope, $scope, $http, etc).  So, because you are using scope as a local variable in your tests, by convention it does not have a '$' in front of it, since it is not injected into your code, whereas $rootScope always is.

For more of an explanation, see here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NnB2NBtoeAY

Essentially, naming does't matter, but its to make your code more readable.